# Format the rows and columns of a range based on variable

Tags: excel, vba, formatting, range, conditional-formatting

I've tried different solutions and had success compiling, but haven't seen results on the spreadsheet for my problem.

I want to format the color of a table on one sheet based off of the values in two cells of a different sheet.

One value will be the length (row number) and one will be the width (column number) and it should be updated every time the values of the cells are changed.  Here is what I have that is not showing any results:

```
Sub Worksheet_Formatting(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim NearWidth As Integer
Dim NearLength As Integer
Dim R As Range

NearWidth = Worksheets("Information").Cells(2, 2).Value
NearLength = Worksheets("Information").Cells(3, 2).Value
R = Range(Worksheets("Antenna Placement").Cells(2, 2).Value, Worksheets("Antenna Placement").Cells(NearLength, NearWidth)) = RGB(0, 255, 0)


End Sub
```

Any explanation as to why this is compiling but results aren't showing up?

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing setting a range, and setting a background color.  Replace your `R = ...` with

```
Set R = Range(Worksheets("Antenna Placement").Cells(2, 2).Value, Worksheets("Antenna Placement").Cells(NearLength, NearWidth))    
R.Interior.Color = RGB(0,255,0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I made the change and here is what I have now:

    `NearWidth = Worksheets("Information").Cells(2, 2).Value
    NearLength = Worksheets("Information").Cells(3, 2).Value
    Set R = Range(Worksheets("Antenna Placement").Cells(1, 1).Value,
    Worksheets("Antenna Placement").Cells(NearLength, NearWidth))
    R.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)

    End Sub`

I have the code in the Antenna Placement window.  Is that wrong?

Comment: What cells are you "watching"? In other words, you said that you want this to run when cells are changed - what cells? Cells B2 and B3 in your Information worksheet?  And this macro should go in a worksheet module (right click the project in the VB window, and Add Module).

Comment: Yes exactly.  Those cells are defining the area that should be displayed on the Antenna Placement sheet